# Word2Vec Skip-Gram para identificar similitudes entre términos de 2 tokens o palabras

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

Quiero extraer similitudes entre dos términos de 2 tokens cada uno con el algoritmo de Word2vec, la variante de Skip-Gram. El código no da error pero no extraigo ninguna similitud en los textos analizados y he revisado manualmente que los términos existen en el texto. Creo que al modificar el código para reconocer términos de 2 tokens estoy haciendo algo mal. No sé si hay alguna variante del algoritmo que permita esta variante.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize 
import warnings 
import gensim 
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
import urllib.request
import re
import nltk

def leerTxt(fichero):
    f = open (fichero,'r')
    mensaje = f.read()
    f.close()
    return mensaje

#Leemos el listado de keywords
listaKeywords = leerTxt("total_keywords.txt").lower().split("\n")
#Leemos los textos completos
listaTextosCompletos = leerTxt("textosCompletos.txt").split("----------------")

for linea in listaKeywords:
    for key in linea.split(";"):
        #si es una keyword de 2 tokens
        if(len(key.strip().split(" ")) == 2):
            key = key.strip()
            print("-----"+key)
            #en cada texto en el que aparezca esa keyword
            for texto in listaTextosCompletos:
                # Limpiamos el texto
                processed_article = texto.lower()
                processed_article = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', processed_article )
                processed_article = re.sub(r'\s+ \s+', ' ', processed_article)
            
                # Preparamos el texto
                all_sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(processed_article)
                all_words2 = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in all_sentences]
                # Eliminamos Stop Words
                from nltk.corpus import stopwords
                for i in range(len(all_words2)):
                     all_words2[i] = [w for w in all_words2[i] if w not in stopwords.words('english')]
                
                 all_words = []
                 i=0
                 for word in all_words2[0]:
                     i = i+1
                     if(i < len(all_words2[0])):
                        all_words.append(word + " " + all_words2[0][i])
                
                 from gensim.models import Word2Vec
            
                 word2vec = Word2Vec(all_words, min_count=1, size= 50,workers=3, window=5, sg = 1)
                 vocabulary = word2vec.wv.vocab
                 #print(vocabulary)
                if(key in vocabulary):
                    v1 = word2vec.wv[key]
                    sim_words = word2vec.wv.most_similar(key)
```

Lo que quiero es extraer similitudes entre mis palabras clave (key) de 2 tokens (por ejemplo, "data source") y los términos de 2 tokens del texto (por ejemplo, "machine learning"). Ambos términos aparecen en el texto por lo que no entiendo por qué no encuentra ninguna similitud.

¿Alguna idea?